# How to change foreground colour of Section title page

Tags: beamer

I have a basic beamer presentation:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% -----------
% Set ISRIC style

\usetheme{example}

% -- Section title pages
\AtBeginSection[]{
  \begin{frame}
  \vfill
  \centering
  \begin{block}{}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,shadow=true,rounded=true]{title}
    \usebeamerfont{title}\insertsectionhead\par%
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \end{block}
  \vfill
  \end{frame}
}

%----------------
% Title and authors

\title{My presentation}

\subtitle{Coded with \LaTeX}

\author[Jane Smith]{Jane Smith}

\institute[Institute of LaTeX Learning]{Institute of LaTeX Learning}

\date{\today}

%====================================================================
\begin{document}

%----------------
% Title frame

{ \setbeamertemplate{footline}{} % no footer on title
\begin{frame}
\titlepage 
\end{frame} 
}

%----------------
% Table of contents

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\tableofcontents
% You might wish to add the option [pausesections]
\end{frame}

%------------------------------------------------
\section{First Section} % Sections can be created in order to organize your presentation into discrete blocks, all sections and subsections are automatically printed in the table of contents as an overview of the talk
%------------------------------------------------

\subsection{Subsection Example} % A subsection can be created just before a set of slides with a common theme to further break down your presentation into chunks

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Paragraphs of Text}
Sed iaculis dapibus gravida. Morbi sed tortor erat, nec interdum arcu. Sed id lorem lectus. Quisque viverra augue id sem ornare non aliquam nibh tristique. Aenean in ligula nisl. Nulla sed tellus ipsum. Donec vestibulum ligula non lorem vulputate fermentum accumsan neque mollis.\\~\\

Sed diam enim, sagittis nec condimentum sit amet, ullamcorper sit amet libero. Aliquam vel dui orci, a porta odio. Nullam id suscipit ipsum. Aenean lobortis commodo sem, ut commodo leo gravida vitae. Pellentesque vehicula ante iaculis arcu pretium rutrum eget sit amet purus. Integer ornare nulla quis neque ultrices lobortis. Vestibulum ultrices tincidunt libero, quis commodo erat ullamcorper id.
\end{frame}

%----------------
\end {document}
```

I would like to tweak the foreground of Section elements, and thus produced this style file:

```
\mode<presentation>
\ProcessOptionsBeamer

% ---------------------------------
% color definitions
\definecolor{ocre}  {RGB}{139,  40, 34}

% ---------------------------------
% set colors of elements
\setbeamercolor{section}{fg=ocre}
\setbeamercolor{section in toc}{fg=ocre}
\setbeamercolor{section title}{fg=ocre}

% ---------------------------------
% settings for Boxes
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]

\mode
<all>
```

In the table of contents the Section element foreground is modified as expected:

[image]

However, in section title pages it is still displayed with the default style:

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `section title` colour for your `beamercolorbox` instead of the `title` colour.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{139,40,34}
\setbeamercolor{section title}{fg=ocre}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]


% -- Section title pages
\AtBeginSection[]{
  \begin{frame}
  \vfill
  \centering
  \begin{block}{}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,shadow=true,rounded=true]{section title}%<- Change here
    \usebeamerfont{title}\insertsectionhead\par%
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \end{block}
  \vfill
  \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\section{First Section} 

\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]